# Prolog - add some elements to same list

Tags: prolog

I have a problem to add elements in a list in Prolog. I use this rule:

```
add(X, L, [X|L]).
```

This rule add an element in the Head of the list.
If i would add some element to the same list i have this problem:

```
add(a, L, L1),
add(b, L1,L2),
add(c, L2,L3). 

L3= [a,b,c]
```

Is there a method to add elements in a list without change the name of variable... L1, L2, L3, but adding they to a single variable L?

Comment: Is there a particular bigger problem context for this scenario that you have in mind? Perhaps there's a different way to achieve your objective.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no: L would have to represent different lists, which is wrong in Prolog.

But you can implement something like this:

```
add_list([], L, L).
add_list([H|T], L, L1) :- add(H, L2, L1), add_list(T, L, L2).
```

Sample usage:

```
?- add_list([1,2,3],X,A).
A = [1, 2, 3|X].

?- add_list([1,2,3],X,A), writeln(A-X), add_list([4,5],Y,X).
[1,2,3|_G1188]-_G1188
X = [4, 5|Y],
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5|Y].

?- add_list([1,2,3],X,A), writeln(A-X), add_list([4,5],Y,X),Y=[].
[1,2,3|_G1224]-_G1224
X = [4, 5],
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
Y = [].
```

Comment: Is it possible insert an element in the head of list, in a same list?

Comment: @JoachimLow no, but you can insert them in the end of the open-ended list, as this answer shows.

Comment: With this solution, to keep adding to the open ended list, don't you need to continue using new, uninstantiated variables? So, following the example, to add `[6,7]` you'd have `add_list([6,7],Z,Y).`? So perhaps it still leaves one with the intractable problem of creating new variable names to instantiate.

Comment: @mbratch `add_list/3` takes care of all the intermediate variables; it only needs two. If you plan on calling it several times, there is a reason for that, a context for that, with its logvars. The difference lists technique always needs two variables - head and end_pointer. End_pointer changes, so every predicate which instantiates it, must be returning a new one. So *its* result provides us with a new uninstantiated logvar that we treat as end_pointer in later code. -- The DCG interface makes both of these logvars implicit. They become explicit in the call `phrase(dcg_rule, List, Rest)`.

Answer (score 2):

That's implicitly done by DCG, adding (hidden) difference list arguments to non terminals.
But without some more detail about your task it's hard to hint about any sensible usage.

SWI-Prolog has actually some serious capability, via non backtrackable data structures, to perform tasks with 'side effects' propagating thru the solution chain, but I'm not sure if it's opportune to hint you about this feature...

*edit* an example of updating an RBTree in a failure driven loop:

```
:- use_module(library(rbtrees)).
:- use_module(library(nb_rbtrees)).

 ordkey :- rb_empty(R),
   forall(member(W, [ls,mkdir,cd,ftp]),
     ( atom_length(W, K),
       (  nb_rb_get_node(R, K, N)
       -> nb_rb_node_value(N, Ws),
          nb_rb_set_node_value(N, [W|Ws])
       ;  nb_rb_insert(R, K, [W])
       )
    )), rb_visit(R, L), writeln(L).

yields

?- ordkey.
[2-[cd,ls],3-[ftp],5-[mkdir]]
```

Comment: could you give a link to something that explains/shows the use that you mention in the last paragraph?

Comment: @WillNess: I placed a small example.

Comment: thank you. "propagating ..." threw me off completely. "accumulation of side effects by solutions in a failure driven loop" would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, as noted, is NO.

The longer answer: You can't add items to an existing list (without creating a new list). Nor can you increment a variable like you might in other languages: you can only create a new variable whose value is the source variable incremented by 1. Prolog data types are all *immutable*. Prolog variables, once bound to a value, **cease to be variable**. Their binding is undone when execution backtracks through the assignment.

Comment: IOW Prolog is a *set once* language.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't just add to an existing list, which corresponds to the direct question being asked, there are some classes of problems which can be solved using a predicate whose solutions are individually items you want to collect in a list, and you can collect them with the ISO predicate, `findall`:

```
determin_item( ..., X ) :-
    % Logic which determines X
    % Could be complex with multiple Prolog statements and various conditionals

findall( X, determine_item(..., X), List ).
```

As a trivial example for the case given:

```
foo(1,a).
foo(1,b).
foo(1,c).
foo(2,e).
foo(3,f).

determine_item( X ) :-
    foo(1, X).  % Trivial example to determine X

findall( X, determine_item(X), List ).
```

Which will generate:

```
List = [a,b,c].
```

Comment: i.e. your answer shows how to, instead of adding elements one by one, create the list at once.

Comment: @WillNess, I agree to a point, but it depends upon what you're looking at. Where the comment says "Trivial example to determine X" there would be logic which selects elements one by one to add to the list. As I had asked the OP and as I mentioned in my answer, it depends on the context of their problem. It's possible the problem could be "remapped" to what I'm showing, but without more information of context, it is indeed difficult to tell. Ultimately, the OP is trying to build a list.