# Putting the results of a query in a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'd like to know how to make a predicate that puts all results obtained from some query

For example if I write

```
?- seek(a, L).
```

would like to get all those results in a list

```
L = [sheet, rule]
```

With the following knowledge base:

```
item([sheet,3,4],[[a,1,4],[b,4,3],[c,1,7]]).

item([pen,5,4],[[f,1,4],[t,2,3],[g,4,4],[b,4,3]]).

item([rule,1,8],[[c,1,4],[a,2,3]]).
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a couple of good ways to do this. Here's one approach.

First, `seek/2` can be defined as the result of finding all of the solutions to the inquiry of seeking each solution one by one:

```
seek( X, L ) :-
    findall( Y, seekone(X, Y), L ).
```

To define `seekone/2`, we would say that "`Y` is a result for `X` if `Y` is at the head of the first list in an `item`, and if the associated list of lists contains `X`:

```
seekone( X, Y ) :-
    item( [Y|_], LL ),    % Y is at the head of an item head-list
    contains( LL, X ).    % LL, the associated list of lists for Y, contains X
```

So when you inquire `seekone( a, Y ).` it will yield each valid result one at a time (in `Y`) until the valid results are exhausted. For example:

```
| ?- seekone(a, Y).

Y = sheet ? ;

Y = rule ? ;

no
| ?-
```

Define `contains/2` to be true if a list of lists (first argument) contains the given element (second argument) as the head of one of its list members:

```
contains( [[X|_]|_], X ).    % X is the head of the 1st list in the list of lists
contains( [_|Tail], X ) :-   % X is contained in the list of lists
    contains( Tail, X ).     %    if it is contained in the Tail of list of lists
```

An example of how `contains/2` works:

```
| ?- contains([[a,1,4],[b,4,3],[c,1,7]], X).

X = a ? ;

X = b ? ;

X = c ? ;

no
| ?-
```

Or

```
| ?- contains([[a,1,4],[b,4,3],[c,1,7]], a).

true ? ;

(1 ms) no

| ?-
```

Or

```
| ?- contains([[a,1,4],[b,4,3],[c,1,7]], d).

no
| ?-
```

Putting all these together, gives you the result you're looking for. Examples:

```
| ?- seek(a, L).

L = [sheet,rule]

yes
| ?- seek(f, L).

L = [pen]

yes
| ?- seek(b, L).

L = [sheet,pen]

yes
| ?-
```

Comment: (it was me, [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19456209/849891) that liked it. I think it is a fine change of POV, to produce the whole list at once instead of one-by-one, if possible. My comment was meant  just as a clarification.) :)

Comment: @WillNess Yeah I didn't take it negative at all. I've read your Prolog posts and respect your input. It did play on my uncertainty about my answer (:)). Maybe I'll undelete it, to add what value it may have in the context.

Comment: Thanks, I'm nowhere near expert though. :) And having an additional POV is always good, it enriches the context exactly as you've said.